# How to connect two Bluetooth low energy shields over arduino boards?

Tags: arduino, bluetooth-lowenergy

Unfortunately I am new in Ble shield and programming of this shield,
first of all I tried to find Mac address of my BLE shields for this reason I plugged BLE shields to arduino then by using PC and uploading some code to microcontroller of arduino made a connection with an android phone.Is there anyone to tell me how to write a simple code as slave and a code as master for having a connection?.I found some code for the bluetooth but Not the Bluetooth low energy ,it was complex also and has used pins,I just want to send some character in sender and receive them in receiver that's it.
thanks

Answer (score 1):

With Bluetooth low energy, only a Central can establish a connection with a Peripheral. One Peripheral can not talk directly to another Peripheral (take a look at [this for more information on roles in BLE](https://devzone.nordicsemi.com/index.php/what-is-a-client-and-server-in-ble)).

Most Arduino shields I know about are meant to be used for connecting an Arduino to a smart phone or similar, not to connect two shields directly. Many of them therefore use chips that are only capable of being a Peripheral, for instance the [nRF8001](https://www.nordicsemi.com/eng/Products/Bluetooth-R-low-energy/nRF8001/%28language%29/eng-GB). If that's the chip on your shields, it will unfortunately not be possible to connect them directly together.

(A Central device, for example a smart phone, would however be capable of passing data between them, if that helps.)